# How to draw lines or grids on a mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i achieve a similar effect? (white border and gray grid)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer: shaders. Long answer: If you can't find one on the asset store, you have to write it yourself, and from experience writing shaders are *really frustrating.*

Comment: The flat shaded look can be achieved by using celshader (ToonShader on Unity Asset Store)

Comment: Hello! Sry not related to the question but is this an asset pack or did you do the modeling yourself? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your models are UV-mapped, you could just add a detail map with a grid texture.

If you are willing to get into shaders, you could use the world position to alter the color of a fragment. Unity has an example of how to use the world position [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html). To get a grid you would use `frac()` on both the x and y coordinates (or whichever plane you want the grid on) and threshold it against the thickness of line you want.

a quick code example here:

```
//in the fragment shader:
c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb, gridColor, frac(worldPos.x / gridSize) < gridThickness)
c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb, gridColor, frac(worldPos.y / gridSize) < gridThickness)
```

Comment: Ok but what if i want the white border to be dynamic?

Comment: @DavideNale Im not sure exactly how they got that effect. It could be a projector, a line renderer or something fancy with stencil buffers. I would ask the developer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your suggestions